# Por que a letra "O" é removida ao combinar o prefixo "Para" com "Olímpíco" na expressão "Jogos Paralímpicos"?

Tags: ortografia, etimologia, prefixos

Fonte oficial: http://www.rio2016.com/paralimpiadas

Neste ano, no Rio de Janeiro, haverá os jogos **O**límpicos e os Paralímpicos.

Por que a letra O de Olímpicos é removida quando combinada com o prefixo "para-"?

Quais as normas gramaticais que regem esta composição?

Comment: Note-se que [paraolímpicos também está correcto](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa-aao/paraol%C3%ADmpico) — aliás, [a entrada para paralímpicos no dicionário da Porto Editora](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa-aao/paral%C3%ADmpico) aponta-nos para a outra entrada.

Comment: @JNat até certo tempo atrás eu percebia a palavra grafada com o "O", realmente.

Comment: Penso que está bem explicado neste link: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/paraolimpico-e-nao-paralimpico-nem-para-olimpico/1929

Comment: @Joum devias converter teu comentário em resposta.

Comment: O Comitê Olímpico Internacional resolveu mudar de Paraolímpicos para Paralímpico.  Essa é a explicação.

Answer (score 6):

Com informações adicionais às prestadas pelo @Joum, temos que foi uma manobra do Comitê Olímpico Internacional para "padronizar" a grafia do termo, aproximando-o à grafia do ingês.

Deste Google Ngram, podemos perceber que o termo na lingua inglesa é "Paralympic", sendo as ocorrências de "paraolympic" desprezáveis.

[image: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paralympic%2C+paraolympic&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1990&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3]

Por fim, temos [nesta referência](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/curiosidades-etimologicas/sai-paraolimpico-entra-paralimpico/) de artigo noticioso a razão do neologismo:

> Não se tratava de erro de digitação. Em novembro do ano passado, quando foi divulgada a logomarca do evento, o Comitê Paraolímpico Brasileiro (CPB), assim chamado desde sua fundação, em 1995, aproveitou para anunciar que estava trocando de nome “para se alinhar mundialmente aos demais países”. Para tanto, deixava um o pelo caminho, tornando-se oficialmente o Comitê Paralímpico Brasileiro. Na mesma data, estipulava um prazo de 18 meses – que vence em maio do ano que vem – para que as entidades a ele filiadas se atualizem ortograficamente.

Logo a grafia sem o "O" foi ingerência corporativa do comitê organizador do evento na língua, para se "adequar" à grafia estrangeira.

Isto em um evento em que a ordem do desfile de abertura muda de acordo com a língua falada no país-sede. Parece-me contramão.

Comment: Em resumo, se me permitem a opinião pessoal, alguém resolveu mudar a palavra tendo pouquíssimo embasamento (ver: http://sualingua.com.br/2012/09/16/ainda-as-paraolimpiadas/) e toda a imprensa seguiu atrás. É estranho e um tanto incômodo; de um dia para o outro começaram a engolir o “O” de forma artificial e nós ficamos aqui pensando “O que houve? Eles podem mutilar a palavra assim e todos aderem, mesmo que não tenha lógica e soe mal?”...

Comment: @marcus a mudança foi feita por marqueteiros com 99% da preocupação em **identidade do produto** e 0,05% na língua. "Vamos engolir o O para padronizar a grafia o máximo possível com a língua inglesa." Mas como eles são detentores da marca, e a imprensa não quer ser banida do evento, seguem os marqueteiros quais ovelhas.

Comment: Pois é, foi isso que aconteceu (mas nem como coisa de marqueteiro isso me convence, a palavra ficou muito dissonante, como se um gato tivesse subido no piano). Mas, para completar, depois que postei, vi que o artigo que eu realmente queria enviar era este: http://sualingua.com.br/2012/09/29/ainda-as-paraolimpiadas-conclusao/

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que pude apurar, é um assunto que levanta alguma celeuma.

**TL;DR:** As duas formas estarão correctas, ainda assim há convenções diferentes nomeadamente no contexto do português europeu vs. português brasileiro.

De acordo com [esta referência](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/577):

> As formas paraolímpico e paralímpico encontram-se ambas registadas em
>   vários dicionários de língua portuguesa e nenhuma delas pode ser
>   considerada incorrecta.
>
> A forma preferencial deverá ser paraolímpico, pois será mais
>   consensual a junção do prefixo para- à palavra olímpico. Neste caso,
>   não há uso de hífen porque o prefixo para- não deve ser seguido de
>   hífen (ex.: paraestatal, parassíntese, paratexto), excepto se a
>   palavra a que se junta começar pela letra h ou pela vogal a (a mesma
>   vogal em que termina o prefixo).
>
> A variante paralímpico pode ser justificável quer pela influência da
>   forma inglesa paralympic, quer por um processo de síncope, comum em
>   português, que consiste na eliminação de um fonema no interior de uma
>   palavra (para- + [o]límpico).
>
> A forma para-olímpico encontra-se apenas registada no Dicionário da
>   Língua Portuguesa Contemporânea da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa e
>   não está de acordo com o uso do hífen com o prefixo para- nas
>   principais obras de referência (por exemplo, no Tratado de Ortografia
>   da Língua Portuguesa, de Rebelo Gonçalves).

Há, contudo, [visões adicionais](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/paraolimpico-e-nao-paralimpico-nem-para-olimpico/1929) que me parecem relevantes (ênfase meu):

> Por tudo o que se apresentou, a AiT recomenda que a forma desejável
>   para grafar o termo em análise é, sem margem para dúvidas, a forma
>   **paraolímpico**.

Na minha opinião, importa ainda distinguir o aspecto informal da questão - aplicabilidade e validade do termo em termos conversacionais e de grafia - da questão de ciência linguística e quadro normativo da língua portuguesa. Penso que ambos os aspectos estarão suficientemente cobertos nas referências apresentadas.

Comment: Eu encontrei *paralímpico* apenas no Priberam e Porto Editora (Infopédia), e ambos remetem para *paraolímpico*. O Houaiss e Aulete têm apenas *paraolímpico*; o da academia *para-olímpico* (mas está escrito na grafia pré-AO); o Michaelis não tem nada.